# 'List of theorems', translated into my language

Tags: theorems, languages, naming, thmtools

I'm using `\listoftheorems` (part of the `thmtools` package) to show a list of all my theorems. It works really well, but it prints "List of theorems" in English; I would obviously prefer it to be in my language, i.e. "Elenco dei teoremi".

What can I do?

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina: Why did you delete your answer? As far as I can see, it's the correct one.

Comment: @lockstep: there was something not quite correct that now I've corrected, and this is a duplicate. I've un-deleted the answer, but perhaps it would be better to close it as duplicate? By the way, I didn't get the notification about your message in my inbox.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use

```
\renewcommand\listtheoremname{Elenco dei teoremi}
```

in the preamble of your document.