# Counters to be used in section (& similar) titles (any TeX)

Tags: titles, counters

I use LaTeX to take notes in University. The notes are divided into chapters which are the single lessons. They are numbered. It's easy to lose track of that lesson number. So I'd like LaTeX to do that in my place. What I'd need is to create a counter and use its value in the chapters' title. Something like a `\newtheorem`, only that can't go in section titles because it generates the error

```
argument of \@sect has an extra }
```

My table of contents starts like this:
[image: Table of contents]
The full table of contents is rather long, so I won't put it all here, as I think this much is already enough. As you can see, there are chapters titled *Lezione xx* (xx being a number), chapters titled *Esercitazione xx*, and chapters of *Esercizi* (respectively, Lesson xx, Exercise lesson xx, Exercises), so I would need two independent counters for *Lezione* and *Esercitazione* to avoid having to number them manually and risking to find myself (as I just did) with two *Esercitazione 14*, no *Lezione 22* and no *Lezione 25*. Is there a way to do that in LaTeX? And is there a way to create a list of all theorems of a particular kind (e.g. if I defined `\newtheorem{defi}{Definizione}`, to create a list of all "`defi`"s)?

Comment: Could you add a full MWE showing what you've already tried in order for us to help you? Besides could you explain further what is your problem with the already existing numbers from the `\chapter` or`\section`... If you use one chapter per lesson the numbers should match, no?

Comment: `\section` already has a counter.  all you need to do is insert a `\label{xxx}` after the `\section`, and then use `\protect\ref{xxx}` in the chapter title.  (the `\protect` is needed here since `\ref` is a "fragile" command; if the `\ref` is just in text, no `\protect` is needed.)

Comment: @LudovicC. what I've already tried is to manually count the lessons. Is there a way to post an image here? This way I can post an image of my table of contents to better explain my question.

Comment: And @barbarabeeton I'll keep your comment in mind but it seems that what you're telling me is how to make a reference to something else in a chapter title. I know that \section has a counter, but what I'm asking can't be dealt with by using that counter, because that way I'd have to have a section with counter 30 (the value for the next Lesson chapter) which I probably will never find in any chapter. What I need is a new independent counter. Once I manage to post the image, you'll see why.

Comment: ![Table of Contents page 1](/Michele's MacBook Pro/Macintosh HD/Users/michelegorini/Desktop/Screen Shot 2013-12-26 at 11.07.19 AM)

That's the path to the image I'd like to post. How do I post it?

Comment: While editing your question you have among the formatting options a small blue frame looking like a picture. It is the way to insert a picture in your question (or answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
\documentclass{report}

\newcounter{le}
\setcounter{le}{0}
\newcommand{\lezione}[1]{Lezione~\arabic{le}:~#1}
\newcommand{\incle}[0]{\refstepcounter{le}}

\newcounter{ei}
\setcounter{ei}{0}
\newcommand{\esercizi}[0]{Esercizi~\arabic{ei}}
\newcommand{\incei}[0]{\refstepcounter{ei}}

\newcounter{ee}
\setcounter{ee}{0}
\newcommand{\esercitazione}[1]{Esercitazione~\arabic{ee}:~#1}
\newcommand{\incee}[0]{\refstepcounter{ee}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\incle
\chapter{\lezione{Foo}}

\incle
\chapter{\lezione{Bar}}

\incei
\chapter{\esercizi}

\incle
\chapter{\lezione{Baz}}

\incee
\chapter{\esercitazione{Bla}}

\end{document}
```

I defined two separate commands for incrementing the counter and calling it in the `\chapter` command in order to keep all the optional functionalities of the `\chapter` command. A "simpler" way would be to merge them but then it is not possible to use the options of the `\chapter` command. Just for information, the command would then be (for the lectures):

```
\newcounter{le}
\setcounter{le}{0}
\newcommand{\lezione}[1]{\refstepcounter{le}
\chapter{Lezione~\arabic{le}:~#1}}
```

and the command to use in the document is simply `\lezione{<title>}`.

Here is the output of both methods for the table of contents:

[image: Output]

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed. thx. Just one question: why are there these tildes (~) in `\lezione`, `\esercizi` and `\esercitazione`, and why do they get typesetted as spaces?

Comment: Glad it suits you, the tildes are the LaTeX sign for space without linebreak. It is recommended to use them whenever you want to be sure that LaTeX won't break the line here (not really needed here, but a good practice to have).

Comment: Ok got it. And what about the other question at the end of my question, about making a theorem list?

Comment: What about [this](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=17679)? Does it help for the last part of your question?

Comment: The list is there. I have 3 problems:
1) I'd like to change the title, and the `\listoftheoremname` in that page, if I try to `\renewcommand` it, gives a `LaTeX Error: \listoftheoremname undefined` error;
2) I'd like to have different lists for different types of theorems, in particular to separate Theorems Definitions Propositions Lemmas Corollaries and such theoretical stuff from the various types of Exercise theorems I have defined;
3) I'd like to label the various theorems to get the labels appearing in the lists rather than just `1 Definizione`, `2 Definizione` and so on.

Comment: In order for your problem to get more attention you should post a new question with only this problem and I am pretty sure that I have already seen such questions on this platform so it is possible and answers exist, even though I don't know them because I never use theorems...

Comment: The label thing is solved by adding [name=yyy,label=thm:...] after \begin{xxx}, xxx being a type of theorem, yyy being typesetted as bold in parentheses () right after the theorem heading, and ... being the label appearing in the list. Trouble is, if I try to put some math more complicated than superscript and subscript in a label (in my case, `\mathbb`), the result is `missing \endcsname inserted` in line xx (in my case, 69) of the .aux file. What's that?

Comment: For the name of the list try [this solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52896/31058) (without the "of" from your attempt). For the remaining troubles have a look in [this documentation](ftp://ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/exptl/thmtools/thmtools.pdf), I am pretty sure you'll find the answer (and if you don't post a new question).