# Multiple lists of theorems with different titles (any TeX, in my case XeLaTeX)

Tags: lists, theorems

I've found out how to use the `thmtools` package to make lists of theorems. My questions on this are:

1. How do I change the title, given that `\renewcommand{\listoftheoremname}{...}` gives a `LaTeX error: \listoftheoremname undefined` error?
2. How do I make multiple lists of different kinds of theorems with different titles?
3. Adding `[name=xxx,label=thm:...]` after `\begin{yyy}` (xxx is a title for the theorem, ... a label appearing in the list, yyy the theorem kind) labels a theorem. If I try to put any maths beyond superscript and subscript (for now I've only tried `\mathbb`) into a label, I get a `missing \endcsname inserted` error related to a line of the .aux files. How do I solve that? MWE:

   ```
   \documentclass[a4paper]{report}  
   \usepackage{thmtools,amssymb}  
   \declaretheorem[name=Definizione]{defi}  
   \begin{document}  
   \begin{defi}[name=$\mathbb R$,label=thm:$\mathbb R$definizione]  
   Ah beh, s\`i beh.  
   \end{defi}  
   \listoftheorems  
   \end{document}
   ```

which gives:
[image: Error message in TeXShop Console].
The same error is obtained by placing a `\ref` in a label. In fact, `\mathbb` gives problems anywhere in those [], just like trying to put $(0,1)$ there, because of that comma.

4. (should be 4) And finally, I'm using theorems with `[subsection]` numbering. Now, in the list, the number overlaps the theorem kind (i.e. I get `1.2.1.1` overlapping `Definizione (Spazio Metrico)`). How do I solve that?

Comment: For the first point try this solution: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52896/31058 . The name of the variable is `\listtheoremname` and not `\listoftheoremname`.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Then there is an issue with http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=17679, since there it says `\listoftheoremname`. The other link's way it works.

Comment: If an answer to a forum is wrong, there's little one can do, except reporting the error in the forum. Since the package documentation mentions `\listtheoremname`, do you trust a forum better?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This could get you started; but without a clear set of specifications from you it's difficult to be more precise.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}

\declaretheorem{theorem}
\declaretheorem[style=definition]{definition}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of theorems}
\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show=theorem]

\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of definitions}
\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show=definition]

\begin{theorem}[Sum]
$1+1=2$
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}[Nice numbers]
A number is \emph{nice} if it looks beautiful.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}[About $C^{1}(0,1)$]
The set $C^{1}(0,1)$ is interesting.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This perfectly solves the first two points. I had no idea one could use `\renewcommand` inside the document, I thought it was confined to the preamble. Thanks @egreg. Just one questions: why use the package `amsthm`? And why `\declaretheorem` and not `\newtheorem`? Is there any difference?

Comment: @MickG I *always* use `amsthm` because of the predefined theorem styles. As you're loading `thmtools`, why not using its interface, that is, `\declaretheorem`?

Comment: You also can define new commands in your preamble, such as \newcommand{\listofdefinitions}{\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of definitions}\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show=definition]}, in order to have a slighly more readable source file.

Comment: I'll answer myself on points 3-4:  
  
3) It seems the shorthands generate problems even here, as every time something must be transfered to a file different from tex and aux (toc, loe, whatever). Maybe it's my TeX distribution that's out of date and presents bugs that produce this effect. Anyway removing the shorthands has solved the problem (apparently, at least).  
4) The list shows the name, not the label.

Comment: OK just kidding: `\mathbb` still gives problems.

Comment: @MickG Is it a quiz show? The example has no `\mathbb` that I can see. I'm not going to guess.

Comment: The example is for point 4 which I have already solved by myself. So I've removed that point and added a `\mathbb`.

Comment: @MickG Add `\usepackage{amssymb}`. LaTeX is powerful but not clairvoyant.

Comment: Thx. I didn't know `\mathbb` came from `amssymb`. Now I know.