# Changing space between number and name in List of theorems

Tags: thmtools

In the list of theorems, I am trying to increase the space between the numbers and the name of the theorem. Unfortunately, my numbers get rather long, so they overlap with the names of the theorems. I would also like to be able to change the title of the list of theorems, since my document is in German, I have included a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subfiles, amsmath, amssymb, color, marvosym, subcaption, tikz, pgf, mathtools, yfonts, hyperref, gensymb, amsthm, thmtools}
\graphicspath{ {Bilder/} }


\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{satz}{Satz}[section]
\newtheorem{defi}[satz]{Definition}
\newtheorem{konv}[satz]{Konvention}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{koro}[satz]{Korollar}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{beme}[satz]{Bemerkung}
\newtheorem{bsp}[satz]{Beispiel}
\newtheorem*{rappel}{Erinnerung}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\begin{defi}[abc]
xyz
\end{defi}

\begin{defi}[abc]
xyz
\end{defi}

\begin{defi}[abc]
xyz
\end{defi}

\begin{defi}[abc]
xyz
\end{defi}

\chapter{Chapter}
\begin{defi}[abc]
xyz
\end{defi}

\begin{defi}[abc]
xyz
\end{defi}

\begin{defi}[abc]
xyz
\end{defi}

\begin{defi}[abc]
xyz
\end{defi}

\chapter{Chapter}
\begin{defi}[abc]
xyz
\end{defi}

\begin{defi}[abc]
xyz
\end{defi}

\begin{defi}[abc]
xyz
\end{defi}

\begin{defi}[abc]
xyz
\end{defi}

\chapter{Chapter}
\begin{defi}[abc]
xyz
\end{defi}

\begin{defi}[abc]
xyz
\end{defi}

\begin{defi}[abc]
xyz
\end{defi}

\begin{defi}[abc]
xyz
\end{defi}

\listoftheorems

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\end{document}
```

This produces the following list of theorems:

[image: List of theorems]

As you can see, as the numbers get bigger, they tend to overlap with the theorems' names. I would like to fix this.

Comment: The question about changing the title is answered in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52878/list-of-theorems-translated-into-my-language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To increase the space between number and name, use the `numwidth` flag. The default width reserved for the numbers column 2.3em. The following increases the width to 3.5em:

```latex
\listoftheorems[numwidth=3.5em]
```

Result:

[image: Theorem list in resulting PDF]

Source: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/exptl/thmtools/thmtools.pdf

Comment: You could add the instruction for how to change the name of the list as requested by the OP.  That's found in the same source.  (It's stored in `\listtheoremname`.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I was going to edit the answer, but then I realized there is another question which already answers this part. I added a comment for the OP with a link to that question instead.